# How do I ping a server 100k times via javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a website that keeps going up and down, and I never know when it's up.
I'd like to be able to constantly ping it so that I can see when it's gone down.

Step 1 is to get the ping working.

Step 2 is to take the results when they time out and send a message to my pager.

I'm only interested in step 1 right now.

Would javascript or flex be the best way?

Thanks

Comment: I hope you have legitimate intentions, as your "ddos" tag is concerning...

Comment: Why do you need to ping it 100,000 times?

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in a day... i figured I'd just round up to 100k.  But if it makes it easier then how do I do it 86400? Unless you think 100K is too low and should do like a million...

Comment: It's a new device that my company just got for me. I hear doctors use em a lot.

Comment: You should accept Nathan's answer, it seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: That is, if you're not ddos-ing....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just want to try a service like: http://www.pingdom.com/, they'll do all that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to put a small xml file on your website like

```
<root>
 <result>ok</result>
</root>
```

Then you try to load the xml file with jquery, check if you get your "ok" or if you get an error or a timeout.

Jquery doc: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings